# error when trying to return InstanceType of extended class

Tags: typescript

So here's my code

```
class Base {
    constructor (public name : string) {}
}
class Extended extends Base {
    get manged_name () {
        return this.name;
    }
}

function GENERATE<T extends typeof Base> (Model : T) : InstanceType<T> {
    const instance = new Model("something");
    return instance;
}
GENERATE(Extended);
```

note: `GENERATE` has been greatly simplified for example purposes

The error I get is `Type 'Base' is not assignable to type 'InstanceType<T>'.`

## Expected

What I'm trying to do is allow any child classes of `Base` to be used as a parameter, and for its instance to be returned. Why is it erroring?

[tsplayground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/MYGwhgzhAEBCkFNoG8CwAoAkMA9gOwgBcAnAV2EJ2OgAoAHUgIxAEtho8wBbJALmiLEWeAOYBKFAF8M09KEgwAogA9CCPABMEG6AlXqNMeBCRosIhIWhcwo7QH1OPWhLOZMxS6WJ5ohABYsEAB0TggA3BiYsrIYAGakeBQs%20NAA4ooAcooASgCCACqKADwFuvqaMIQAnnQIOHFwiAB8tACyOFog0PwFEvwAkgSEtsAIBbUIpa1uuMPQwkSjSAC8HAgA7tAdXTQARBA4PAHCIntikViehN6%20iyNJETIYGdn5RTQqapraF0A)

Comment: The compiler cannot easily reason about [conditional types](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/conditional-types.html) that depend on [generic](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/generics.html) type parameters; `InstanceType<T>` is essentially opaque to the compiler.  I would strongly suggest changing so that `T` is the instance type and you are passing a value of type `new(name: string)=>T`, like [this](https://tsplay.dev/WJy45m).  Does that address your question and I can write up an answer explaining?  Or am I missing something?

Comment: @jcalz well, if the compiler has trouble with understanding the whole flow, then no way around it. However, would `new (...args : ConstructorParameters<typeof Base>) => T` be better, since it doesn't require manually changing the type if `Base` so happens to update?

Comment: I *guess*, but if the implementation calls `new Model("something")` then the "morally correct" type is `new (name: string) => T`, not `new (...args: ConstructorParameters<typeof Base>) => T`, since you are not passing in a constructor parameter that depends on `typeof Base` at all.  If you update `Base`'s constructor to be incompatible, then something will break somewhere no matter what you do, at least with the current implementation of `generate()`. I'd think it's a matter of opinion on where such an error should surface, so I'll probably not talk much about this in my forthcoming answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Inside your `generate()` function, the inferred type of `new Model("something")` is just `Base`.  That's because accessing the [construct signature](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/functions.html#construct-signatures) on a [generic](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/generics.html) constructor reduces that constructor to its constraint.  See [ms/TS#47502](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/47502) for a source.  So instead of being specific to `T`, the compiler has widened the instance type all the way to `Base`.

Furthermore, since [the `InstanceType<T>` utility type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/utility-types.html#instancetypetype) is [implemented](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/blob/e6808c429079d132b906102e0a4194c2f346ac80/lib/lib.es5.d.ts#L1541) as a [conditional type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/conditional-types.html) like this:

```
type InstanceType<T extends abstract new (...args: any) => any> = 
  T extends abstract new (...args: any) => infer R ? R : any;
```

and since the `T` type inside the body of your `generate()` function is a [generic](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/generics.html) type parameter, that makes `InstanceType<T>` a conditional type that depends on a generic type parameter.  And, alas, the TypeScript compiler can't really verify that anything is assignable to such types.  They are essentially opaque to the compiler.  See [microsoft/TypeScript#48234](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/48234), [microsoft/TypeScript#48746](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/48746) and undoubtedly many others for a source for that.

---

That means you are trying to assign the too-wide type `Base` to the opaque  type `InstanceType<T>`, and it fails.  If we want the compiler to be able to follow your logic, I'd recommend refactoring so that the generic type parameter corresponds to the *instance* type instead of the constructor type, like this:

```
function generate<T extends Base>(Model: new (name: string) => T): T {
    const instance = new Model("something");
    return instance; // okay
}
generate(Extended); // okay
```

Note how the `Model` parameter is given a construct signature which returns type `T` when called.  Meaning that `new Model("something")` produces a value of type `T`, which is just what we want.

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/HYQwtgpgzgDiDGEAEB5ATgSwOZIN4FgAoASHgBsQookAhS5Ak0ge2CgBc0BXed5tABQwuAIzIZ4SUJABcSDpmBYAlHiQBfIsU0lylagFEAHuwjAAJhHNIIJs+ep0oDLcSwR2SMCCVWA+tIQAqqMxGFoHlxowEjsABYYUAB0gQDcrjraRFoAZlzAvBisSO7AEGggpgA8ACo2dhbU7ACeMBDMObT0AHwCALLMlmRyNcpyAJJs7D6INa0Qtd14rvCsHEgYUzPIALxSEADuSANDAgBEUMyQ8ZtYZ8rpTBHsUTGbHNuPWSSl5ZVBxlMFisDyIOiIeioXWcy10a04PD4gmEYgkUnAEDkCluIQ0YIhFChgPsVnqQIc0JcPw8Xh87nMAQxwVh4Ui0ViCWSaS0OnBhDyBXYRRivwq1TqtnJjh6-UGEGG+yOAkCWM4OKQOyWoxGLNWUw2WwKu0VxzlZHOl2uCSU9y+z1eBo+RseOlF-wExOB5geQA)